# Where (or even any kind of join) doesn't work with Temp table in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have to collect data from many sources into a temp table before performing another SELECT on this table and another table. The temp table has a column called RoomID while the table (which I want to join with my temp table) also has a column called RoomID (I join these 2 tables to get more info about specified Room via its RoomID), but the returned rows are not all rows (all which I think should meet the WHERE condition).

Here is my temp table (after creating and perform a SELECT on it like this: `SELECT * FROM MyTempTable`):

```
ID1    |    Name1   |    ID2    |  Name2  |   RoomID
NULL        NULL          2          A           2
 2          A            NULL      NULL          2
 1          B            NULL      NULL          3
 3          C            NULL      NULL          4
 4          D             5          E           8
```

All the values in RoomID are populated and all these RoomIDs are also present in the table I want to join with MyTempTable, here is that table (call it Room):

```
RoomID     |    Name    |     Note
 1           Dining-room      NULL
 2           Bathroom         NULL
 3           Pantry           NULL
 4           Living room      NULL
 5           Sitting room     NULL
 6           Music room       NULL
 7           Office room      NULL
 8           Library          NULL
```

With those tables above, the following query should return all the matched rows as you (and I expect):

```
SELECT ID1, Name1, ID2, Name2, MyTempTable.RoomID as [RoomID], Name as [Room Name], Note 
FROM   MyTempTable, Room 
WHERE  MyTempTable.RoomID=Room.RoomID
```

But it doesn't. I want to say more about MyTempTable, in fact it is created from 3 UNIONs, and all the values in its ZoomIDs are collected from other tables (which take part in the UNION clauses). I don't know if it matters. However the SELECT performs on the last MyTempTable shows that MyTempTable does have a column of RoomID populated with some rows. Here is what it should be after performing the SELECT above:

```
ID1    |    Name1   |    ID2    |  Name2  |   RoomID    |   Room Name    |  Note
NULL        NULL          2          A           2          Bathroom        NULL
 2          A            NULL      NULL          2          Bathroom        NULL
 1          B            NULL      NULL          3          Pantry          NULL
 3          C            NULL      NULL          4          Living room     NULL
 4          D             5          E           8          Library         NULL
```

But there isn't such a full result, the result contains only 2 rows and I even don't know why they are always those 2 rows not of any other 2 rows in the set of rows above:

```
ID1    |    Name1   |    ID2    |  Name2  |   RoomID    |   Room Name    |  Note
 2          A            NULL      NULL          2          Bathroom        NULL
 1          B            NULL      NULL          3          Pantry          NULL
```

I guess, the MyTempTable.RoomID refers to the original table in the UNION which I used to create MyTempTable, because I can see that all the returned rows seem to only belong to that table.

This is really strange, and if it's not a bug, I think the things we can do with Temp table in SQLite are so limited.

## Update

You can see that, there is no row with ZoomID equal to 4 returned, but if I change the SELECT to this, it's returned - why is that?

```
SELECT ID1, Name1, ID2, Name2, MyTempTable.RoomID as [RoomID], Name as [Room Name], Note 
FROM   MyTempTable, Room 
WHERE  MyTempTable.RoomID=4 and Room.RoomID=4
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that, all the fault belongs to me. I made a mistake in creating my tables where in this the ZoomID has type of varchar and in that it has type of int. The difference in types makes the Where Condition unable to be met. And it seems that the auto-conversion is applied only when there is at least 1 constant (like 4 above) in the comparison expression.

Sorry!